# Conceptual Question: What is the purpose of dotting with the normal in Divergence Theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the Divergence Theorem in this form $$\int_U \nabla\cdot F\,dV_n=\oint_{\partial U}F\cdot n\,dS_{n-1}$$

I am still not entirely sure what is the purpose of "dotting" with the normal as in $F\cdot n$?

How do we intuitively understand why must we do that?

Thanks for answering this very basic question!

Comment: A physically meaningful way to approach this question would be to instead say: suppose $u(x,t)$ is transported with velocity $F(x)$, i.e. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+F(x) \cdot \nabla_x u(x,t)=0$. Then there are two different things going on: $\frac{d}{dt} \int_U u(x,t) dx = \int_U \nabla \cdot F(x) dx$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \int_U u(x,t) dx = \int_{\partial U} F \cdot n dS$. We then get the equality between the two different representations of the flux. One drawback to this approach to the problem is that you then have to explain why the transport equation means what it means...

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: Let $S$ be an orientable surface with say the outward pointing normal $n$. Then $F \cdot n$ is the length of the projection of $F$ onto $n$. Therefore $F \cdot n$ is giving you the amount of fluid flowing from the inside of your surface to the outside at some point $P$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parametric representation
$$(u,v)\mapsto {\bf x}(u,v)$$
of $\partial U$ then the (signed) amount $d\Phi$ of fluid passing through an "infinitesimal piece of surface" at ${\bf x}(u,v)$ per unit of time is equal to the volume of the prism spanned by the three vectors $${\bf F}(u,v),\quad {\bf x}_u\>du, \quad{\bf x}_v\>dv\ .$$ Denoting the area element in the parameter plane by ${\rm d}(u,v)$ we therefore have 
$$\eqalign{d\Phi&={\bf F}(u,v)\cdot({\bf x}_u\times {\bf x}_v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)\cr &={\bf F}(u,v)\cdot{\bf n}(u,v)\>|{\bf x}_u\times {\bf x}_v|\>{\rm d}(u,v)\cr &={\bf F}(u,v)\cdot{\bf n}(u,v)\>{\rm d}\omega\ ,\cr}$$
whereby ${\rm d}\omega$ denotes the scalar area element on $\partial U$.
It follows that the total flux $\Phi$ of ${\bf F}$ out of $U$ is given by
$$\Phi=\int_{\partial U}{\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega\ .$$
This way of writing the flux is loaded with superfluous square roots, however.